# How to use ssh tunneling to forward a *service* like X11 or authentication?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to create a service that will allow me to display documents and media (think PDF and JPEG) that are stored in the filesystem of a remote server to which I connect by `ssh`.  X11 forwarding doesn't cut it because it's too slow.  Instead I want to design a protocol that will copy files from the remote system on demand, then display them.

My question is twofold:

1. How do I acquire a port on the remote machine?   Since I may have multiple connections going, I cannot simply use a single well-known port—I will have to allocate a port dynamically.
2. Once I have my port, how do I communicate it to the display applications on the remote machine?  SSH X11 forwarding communicates by setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable, and agent forwarding communicates by setting the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.  Perhaps I can do something creative with a remote command?

I welcome any ideas.

Comment: You still need a well-known port if for no other reason than to negotiate a dynamic port between client and server...  Have you tried using compression on the ssh X forwarding?  It has helped me in the past.

Comment: @Norman Ramsy: if regular X11 is too slow wouldn't simply FreeNX over ssh be an option?

Comment: @Lucas: X forwarding and agent forwarding use a well-known environment variable instead of a well-known port.  I think if I could figure out how to do that, it would solve most of my problem. I have not tried compression---because most of my trouble is latency, not bandwidth, I'm not optimistic.

Comment: @NormanRamsey, so, if its latency, i dont see how ssh is the problem.  I use ssh port forwarding for nearly everything including X, RDP, database...  Dont see any issues.  Do you experience the same latency issues when not using ssh?  How about just a proxy like squid or something similar?  To the best of my knowledge, most of the latency on an ssh tunnel is in the initial negotiation.  The rest of the session should be _nearly_ as fast as unencrypted...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a remote port? If you can ssh into the remote machine, why not run a command and send data back over the ssh command, like rsync, Mercurial, Git, and so on do. SSH can provide an 8-bit clean connection, so it's just like having a socket connection.

To be clear, what i am suggesting is:

1. SSH from origin to the destination
2. In the SSH session, run a command on the destination that writes data to its standard output
3. The standard output is sent over the SSH connection from destination to origin
4. Collect the data that emerges from the standard output of SSH on the origin machine

There is then no need to open a particular port on either the origin or the destination.

Indeed, if what you really want is "a protocol that will copy files from the remote system on demand", how about SCP, SFTP, or rsync over SSH?

Comment: Tom, I think I don't understand your answer.  Typically I *can't* ssh back to the point of origin because that machine is behind a firewall.

Comment: I've added more of an explanation. I don't think you need to SSH back to the origin, or to open any ports at all.

Comment: I think this would work, but I want to trigger the behavior from a shell running at the destination, not the origin.  I also want two-way communication, so for example the destination can send *Display the file with this SHA1 hash* and the origin can send *Give me the contents of the file with this SHA1 hash*.  In any case your expanded answer has given me food for thought, thanks and +1

Comment: Aha, i see. You might be interested in [zssh](http://zssh.sourceforge.net/), which lets you send and receive files through a sort of side-channel in an SSH session, driven by commands run on the remote host. You might be able to drive the `sz` command from a script which does your SHA1 lookup, and then integrate file transfer and display on the local machine.

Comment: yes, zssh looks kind of interesting, but it's still controlled from the client side.  I want something controlled from the remote side.  But maybe I can just get the client to push a `setenv` down the pipe and take things from there.  (Following this link also led me to ssh multiplexing, which looked interesting at first but I think may be purely a performance play.)